# Генерация документации в Sandcastle Help File Builder

Tags: c#, документация, sandcastle

Генерирую документацию в Sandcastle Help File Builder. 
У меня в проекте не у всех элементов было описание

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
```

И при генерации ловлю ошибка типа:

> BuildAssembler : warning : ShowMissingComponent: [Project] Missing  documentation

Когда добавил описание ко всем элементам - документация сгенерировалась.
Соответственно можно ли как-то сгенерировать документацию, чтобы не у всех элементов было описание?

**Add:** Документация как-то да сгенерировалась, хотя ничего не менял.

Comment: warning - это предупреждение, оно не прерывает процесс генерации. в чем суть вопроса? :)

Comment: Проблема в том, что после этого предупреждения все как зависает, 
а в конце - SHFB: Error BE0043: Unexpected error detected in last build step.  See output above for details.
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.RunProcess(String fileToRun, String args)
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.Build()
Пару раз удалось собрать, сам не знаю почему, сейчас и дальше не работает.

Comment: значит ищите в логах именно ошибку, а не предупреждение. хотя бы просто поиском слова error

Comment: Только это
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\DDD\Build1xHelpFile.proj(41,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location &quot;C:\Users\Name\Desktop\DocBFryc\HHC.EXE&quot; is invalid.
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\DDD\Build1xHelpFile.proj(52,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file &quot;C:\Users\Name\Desktop\DDD\Output\HtmlHelp1\Documentation.chm&quot; because it was not found.
    Last step completed in 00:00:01,6095

Comment: так впишите это в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The specified task executable location "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\DocBFryc\HHC.EXE" is invalid.

у вас неправильно задан путь к Help 1 компилятору. Уберите его из настроек (оставьте пустым), или впишите правильный - и все заработает.

Вот похожая ошибка на форуме проекта: [Error when Compiling HTML Help](https://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/541600)

Comment: Спасибо. Путь был пустой, но после того как задал путь - все заработало.